# Email field in Contact Form 7 looks different

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on the contact form on this page:
http://www.thundermailer.com/contact-us/

Am using a plugin called Contact Form 7. The email field is different than the other fields, any idea how can I make it the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your theme's CSS is only targeting inputs of types `text` and `password`

You need to either add a selector for email inputs on your current CSS rules or add a new rule that sets all the required styles for email inputs

The relevant parts that you need to change are:

Line 571 of blue_theme.css:

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"],form input[type="email"], form select, textarea {
    border-top: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background: #f3f3f3 url(images/input_bg.png) repeat-x;
    color: #868686;
}
```

And Line 1654 of main.css

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"], form input[type="email"], form select, textarea {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```

Of course you can also change the type of your input to `text` but then you lose the added extras of using HTML5 like automatic validation and custom keyboard on mobile devices

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. Although, now 2 validation messages seem to overlap each other, if you leave the required fields blank, or entered an invalid email. Any help?

Comment: Really sorry, not sure what happened. I refreshed and the page is only displaying one error message per field now. Me bad. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On analysing the code, the input type of email field is given as "email", make it "text".

Comment: That must be generated from the plugin. But will there be any problem if I changed that... I am sure it must serve a purpose to have the input type as email?

Comment: No there won't be any problem. Could you please paste the code of that email section. I will get change the code for you in the correct way.

Comment: I know what purpose it might serve... maybe it is used in the email validation. If I entered an invalid email in that field, it will throw a message "email address seems invalid".

Comment: Changing the input type is not the right answer, we should strive to implement HTML5 standards, the problem is that the theme's CSS was not built with these in mind

Answer (score 0):

There are two spots in your css where you reference form input[type="text"], without adding form input[type="email"].

After making these changes, it appears the same as your other input fields. You could simply change type='email' in your email input field to type='text'; though, you could just find those two sections (one in your main.css, and one in blue theme.css) where you set the border, background, padding and other settings.